# Does StratifiedKFold splits the same each time a for loop is called?

Tags: python, cross-validation, k-fold

I use StratifiedKFold and a form of grid search for my Logistic Regression.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)
```

I call this for loop for each combination of parameters:

```
for fold, (trn_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y)):
```

My question is, are `trn_idx` and `test_idx` the same for each fold every time I run the loop?

For example, if `fold0` contains `trn_dx = [1,2,5,7,8]` and `test_idx = [3,4,6]`, is `fold0` going to contain the same `trn_idx` and `test_idx` the next 5 times I run the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the stratified k-fold split is fixed if `random_state=SEED` is fixed. The `shuffle` only shuffles the dataset along with their targets before the k-fold split.

This means that each fold will always have their indexes:

```py
x = list(range(10))
y = [1]*5 + [2]*5

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for fold, (trn_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(skf.split(x, y)):
    print(trn_idx, test_idx)
```

Output:

```py
[1 2 4 5 7 9] [0 3 6 8]
[0 1 3 5 6 8 9] [2 4 7]
[0 2 3 4 6 7 8] [1 5 9]
```

No matter how may times I run this code.